# JBoss-DataSource Cration and usage

Tags: jboss

I am using Jboss AS 5.1.x server . when i am using DataSource object with jndi name in my java program i am getting errors while connecting to the server manager connection pool.
Please verify below mentioned details and give me suggestions why it is giving errors.

To place the DataSource to Jndi we mustly put *-ds.xml file so i had placed mysql-ds.xml file in default/deploy folder with follwed tags.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <datasources>
  <local-tx-datasource>
 <jndi-name>MySqlDS</jndi-name>
 <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql</connection-url>
 <driver-class>org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver</driver-class>
 <user-name>root</user-name>
 <password>root</password>
<exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.
  jdbc.vendor.MySQLExceptionSorter
  </exception-sorter-class-  name>
    <new-connection-sql>SELECT 1</new-connection-sql>
    <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
 <metadata>
    <type-mapping>mySQL</type-mapping>
  </metadata>
  </local-tx-datasource>
 </datasources>
```

After placing this xml file in deploy folder , while i browse Jndiview i had found one tag in jnditree with MySqlDs in java:
                                |MySqlDs

For using above binded jndi name i had used follwed java program(standalone).

```
// JndiDsConTest.java
import javax.naming.*; //(jndi api)
import javax.sql.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class JndiDsConTest
 {
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
{


    //Jbosss
     Hashtable ht=new Hashtable();
         ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
               "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
    ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"jnp://localhost:1099");

    // create InitialContext obj
    InitialContext ic=new InitialContext(ht);
                                // represents conectivity with registry s/w

    // get DataSoruce obj ref from registry
    DataSource ds=(DataSource)ic.lookup("java:/MySqlDS");
     //DataSource ds=(DataSource)ic.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/MySqlDS");

     // get con obj from Jdbc Con pool
     Connection con=ds.getConnection();

     // write jdbc persistance logic
     Statement st=con.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select count(*) from  employee");

      if(rs.next())
      {
          System.out.println("count of records :"+rs.getInt(1));
      }

      // close jdbc objs
      rs.close();
      st.close();
      // release con obj back to con pool
      con.close();
      }//main
     }//class
```

when i am running above class file i am getting follwed error stacktrace.

```
    D:\JAVA DRIVER\JAVA\JNDI>java JndiDsConTest
   Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.CommunicationException: Could not obtain
   connection to any of these urls: MySqlDS and discovery failed with error: javax
   .naming.CommunicationException: Receive timed out [Root exception is java.net.So
   cketTimeoutException: Receive timed out] [Root exception is javax.naming.Communi
  cationException: Failed to connect to server MySqlDS:1099 [Root exception is jav   
  ax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server MySqlDS:1099
  [Root exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: MySqlDS]]]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1763)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:693)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:686)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at JndiDsConTest.main(JndiDsConTest.java:25)
  Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server MySq
  lDS:1099 [Root exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to
   connect to server MySqlDS:1099 [Root exception is java.net.UnknownHostException:
  MySqlDS]]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:335)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1734)
    ... 4 more
   Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server
   MySqlDS:1099 [Root exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: MySqlDS]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:305)
    ... 5 more  
   Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: MySqlDS
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(Unknown Source)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.TimedSocketFactory.createSocket(TimedSocketFactory
    .java:81)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:301)
    ... 5 more
```

Could please find me the reason for errors stacktrace and solve it.

ThankYou in adavance.

Comment: Few things to look out for - 1) Make sure your connection string is correct, 2) Make the db is up, 3) Make sure you are using the correct JDBC driver.

Comment: Yes all this settings are fine , but connection is going to be refused..

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the stacktrace message `java.net.UnknownHostException: MySqlDS`, I'd say the JDBC driver is looking for a host named "MySqlDS", so I don't think it's getting the information from your mysql-ds.xml file, at least not the way you've described it here.

Here's some of my code that works in JBoss 5.1.0.  (I'm showing your datasource name rather than my original one.)

```
javax.naming.Context ic = new javax.naming.InitialContext();
javax.naming.Context ctx = (javax.naming.Context) ic.lookup("java:");
javax.sql.DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/mysqlds");
conn = ds.getConnection();
```

Off the top of my head, I don't know if the JNDI lookup is case-sensitive.  I've always used lowercase myself.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

```
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    resp.setContentType("application/json");

    try {
        DataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DataSourceFactory();
        IDAOFactory dAOFactory = new DAOFactoryImpl(dataSourceFactory);
        IServiceFactory serviceFactory = new ServiceFactoryImpl(dAOFactory);

        IItemService itemService = serviceFactory.getItemService();
        ArrayList<Item> allItems = itemService.getAll();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

        String list = gson.toJson(allItems);

        out.write(list);
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        ServletException servletException = new ServletException(ex);
        throw servletException;
    } finally {
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    }

}
```

function loadOrders() {

```
var ajaxConfig = {
    type: "GET",
    url: "getAllOrders",
    async: true,
    contentType: "",
    data: "",
    dataType: "json"
};

$.ajax(ajaxConfig)
        .done(function (response) {
            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                var html = "<tr> \
                            <td>" + response[i].orderId + "</td> \
                            <td>" + response[i].date + "</td>\
                            <td>" + response[i].customerId + "</td> \
                        </tr>";
                $("#tbleOrders tbody").append(html);
            }
        })
        .fail(function (xhr, status, errorMessage) {
            alert("Faild to load data !!");
        });
```

}